# Exact meaning of "arrondie au plus près"

Tags: sens, nombres, mathématiques

I am taking part in a logic puzzle competition, which is organized by a Fédération Française des Jeux Mathématiques. Translation by a local organiser in my country has some flaws and I need to know exactly what to do in every problem.

In [problem 16](http://www.ffjm.org/upload/fichiers/QuartsdeFinale/QuartsdeFinaleIndividuels2013.pdf), there's this phrase: *arrondie au plus près*. Full sentence:

> Quelle est, en cm² et arrondie au plus près, l’aire du dodécagone ?

How should I interpret it, is it just rounding up (e.g. 48,9987 → 49)?

Comment: It's rounding to the closest, which differs from rounding up for e.g. 48,19.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase *arrondi au plus près* is short for “*arrondi à la valeur la plus proche*”, which means “rounded to nearest”. The expected answer when the distance to the previous value is the same as the distance to the next is left unspecified.

In this case, “*arrondi à l'unité la plus proche*” would have been less ambiguous. *Arrondir à la dixaine* (tens), *à la centaine* (hundreds), *au dixième* (tenths), etc. are different possibilities.

Note: *rounded up* is “*arrondi par excès*” or “*arrondi à la valeur supérieure*” and *rounded down* is “*arrondi par défaut*” or “*arrondi à la valeur inférieure*”.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to "round up" :

- ceiling  (1,458 -> 1,46):  “arrondi à la valeur supérieure”
- floor  (1,458 -> 1,45): “arrondi à la valeur inférieure” or "troncature",
- nearest (1,458 -> 1,46), (1,452 -> 1,45)  “arrondi à la valeur la plus proche” or simply "arrondi".

Comment: La troncature est un arrondi vers 0, et non pas à la valeur inférieure (ce n'est pas la même chose pour les nombres négatifs). De plus, dans le cas de l'arrondi à la valeur la plus proche, il y a l'ambiguïté du nombre 0,5. Il n'y a donc pas que trois méthodes d'arrondi.